# Can i put a .doc or .txt for displaying data in html

Tags: html

I just wonder if i can put a .doc or .txt files in the html instead of placing too much code in showing the data. I think that should be some method but i m not sure about it

Comment: You can load it in using javascript.   .docx is an xml file and could in theory be parsed, but it would be a pain. Maybe there's a library made for that.  Loading a.txt file is pretty easy though.   Are you using jQuery or some other library that has helper methods for that?

Comment: i m using jQuery but i got no idea what function i can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a direct URL to a `.doc` or `.txt` file on your server without even using HTML if that's most convenient. A browser will typically display `.txt` files right in the browser itself. A `.doc` file would likely be offered to store on disk so you can use a program like `Word` to view it.

If you are talking about embedding data into an existing HTML page there are ways to do so but it would require knowing more about your server. Are you using PHP to respond to requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number of methods to acheive this. Most commonly used are php includes if the server is capable of executing php scripts. Javascript is also commonly used and there are many examples of how to do this.  This could also be achieved using SSI (server side include) but this method is not commonly used and requires renaming the file with .shtml extension 
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not a very useful answer without examples.  Consider adding some to give your answer some actual value.